# stop reloading site while submit-event

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins, return, alert

Hey there i have this little script which runs while user clicks on "submit":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(){

    var username = $("#username-field").val();
    if(username) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'check.php',
            data: {data: JSON.stringify(username)},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.result == 0) {
                    alertify.error( data.error );
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    } else { 
        alertify.alert( "You forgot to type username" );
        return false;
    }
  });
});
```

When i type something in the username-input-field ... ,the script "check.php" returns 0, but there is no alertify.error displayed.

Instead of displaying alertiy.error(data.error) the page is reloaded? why? i set "return false", so it should not be refrehed.

BUT:
If i type nothing in the input-field the if-clause becomes false and this works:

```
    } else { 
        alertify.alert( "You forgot to type username" );
        return false;
    }
```

So why does this work, but the ajax-example aboth not?

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet, should fix your issue:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function () {
        var username = $("#username-field").val();
        if (username) {
            $.ajax({
                context:this, //set context here
                url: 'check.php',
                data: {
                    data: JSON.stringify(username)
                },
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.result == 0) {
                        alertify.error(data.error);
                    }
                    else this.submit(); //submit form using DOM node property (not calling jq handler)
                }
            });
        } else {
            alertify.alert("You forgot to type username");            
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: i did it exactly this way now, what happens: the script returns 0, the page is not reloaded but there is also no error-message, why?

Comment: @user3080627 You want to submit FORM even result == 0 ??? This is not how i read your opening post code

Comment: no, when result==0, than display error-message and dont submit

Comment: Maybe: `if ($.trim(data.result) === "0")` If not, post value of `console.log(data.result)`

Comment: Ok so, are you sure the success callback is called? Have you tried to debug it yourself using an alert() instead of this function alertify that nobody knows?

Comment: ok there was a php-error, sorry, now it works, thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to return false outside of the `$.ajax` call, IIRC. The callback return is not the same thing as the return value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

move the return false to the end, outside of the if statement. you want to always return false, so logically there's no point in it being inside of the if statement because it doesn't depend on the condition.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(){
    var form = this;
    var username = $("#username-field").val();
    if(username) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'check.php',
            data: {data: JSON.stringify(username)},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.result == 0) {
                    alertify.error( data.error );
                    //return false;
                }
                else {
                    form.submit();
                }
            }
        });
    } else { 
        alertify.alert( "You forgot to type username" );
        //return false;
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

The reason it didn't work as-is is because by the time you would have returned in the success callback, your page has already reloaded. The success callback wasn't even being executed.